# inject ng-template into component

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, angular10, ng-template

I'm trying to inject a template into component and it works perfectly like this:

`app.component`:

```html
<app-parent>
    <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
          <div class="myClass">{{ item.name }}</div>
    </ng-template>
</app-parent>
```

`parent.component`:

```js
item: Item;
@ContentChild('itemTemplate', { static: false }) itemTemplateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
```

```html
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplateRef" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: item}"></ng-container>
```

Until now everything is OK. Now I want to create a child component to encapsulate the ng-template in an independent component so the parent become simply:

```html
<app-parent>
    <app-child></app-child>
</app-parent>
```

and the child takes the insider template

```html
<ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
      <div class="myClass">{{ item.name }}</div>
</ng-template>
```

But it doesn't work like this.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vecpfv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Could you expand on *"doesn't work"*?

Comment: if you are creating a child component you might wanna pass `item` to it.

Comment: @Shubanker I can't because I'am creating a generic Module, I have only to define templates, so you think that it isn't possible to encapsulate ng-template into a component!, do you think that there isany other solution or article explaining how to encapsulate ng-template (without the need of passing item) ?